# What kind of structure is beeing used in the following?

Tags: meaning-in-context, sentence-construction, sentence-structure

I was listening to a video teaching about **WEB API IN ASP.NET Core** which is related to Programming Languages. However I came across the following text:

> one of the most important ideas here is the server is stateless, so
> you're not **going to care between** the request you're stuck **between the
> same server**. a request is coming in, server will try to fulfill it and
> then it's going to forget about it as soon as it sends the response.
> ...

So when I got to the highlighted part above, I wondered if there was a kind of structure being used? And also what does exactly that part mean or talk about or what the reason of using the word "between" in two times is?

Would anyone explain it to me?

Comment: That's spoken language, I guess? It doesn't make sense.

Comment: I agree, it sounds very strange.  Can you give us a link to the video?

Comment: @stangdon but there is no reachable link! because I've bought it from `udemy.com`

Comment: It is not grammatical and doesn't really make sense, but spoken English is not always perfect. It clearly means that it doesn't matter which server each request gets to, so you don't have to worry that each multiple requests get sent to the same server.